# How to generate update by select?

Tags: sql, oracle

I heard about possibility generates update/insert statements using select from dual table. I tried to create some statement but, I always get invalid identifier.

My statement:

```
    select 'update some_table_1 t1 set t1.s_name = ' || some_table_2.s_name ||' 
where some_table_2.s_code = some_table_1.code; ' from dual;
```

For example my situation is:
Table `some_table_1` column `s_name` is updating by data from `some_table_2` column  `s_name` and I want 
to create update statments but only for rows which need it.

How to do it correctly ?

EDIT:
Look on my answer, it is very helpful to understand what I mean.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found  how to do it correctly, general example:

```
   select 'update table_name set column_name = 
'||variable_from_target_table||' where column_code = 
'||variable_from_target_table_2||';' from target_table;
```

For Example:

```
  select  'update some_table_1 set
  s_name = ''' ||s_name|| ''' where s_code = ''' ||s_code|| ''';' from some_table_2;
```

This generates updates:

```
update some_table_1 set s_name = 'Jon' where s_code = 'Y';
update some_table_1 set s_name = 'Adam' where s_code = 'Y';
update some_table_1 set s_name = 'Matt' where s_code = 'Y';
update some_table_1 set s_name = 'Jess' where s_code = 'Y';
update some_table_1 set s_name = 'Carl' where s_code = 'Y';
```

I think this is useful when you want to generate many statements.

Comment: I hope your real statements are more complex than in given example. For such update you do not need any dynamic statements.

Comment: Thanks @Ice.  I was spending too much time on this to get it to work with Sqlite.

Answer (score 2):

```
select 'update some_table_1 t1 set t1.s_name = ''' +  D.CODE + ''' 
where some_table_2.s_code = some_table_1.code; ' from ADMDEPTMAST D;
```

I am execute above query in **SQL2008**

Comment: I want to generete updates not to update the table :) Look at my answer :)
@Karthick Rajan